# OCR an iOS/Android messaging app screenshot

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have a project where I need to convert a screenshot from a messaging application and convert it into a machine readable format (perhaps JSON). I'm asking if you can outline a basic approach for my algorithm. I intend to write my algo in Python.

1. How to persist the back-and-forth/conversation format. Should I split the source image into separate chunks, one chunk for each blue/white speech bubble? I would subsequently feed those individual speech bubbles into an OCR engine, and maintain ordering.
2. Which OCR engine would perform best for screenshots? Obviously my source images are not handwritten. The text is machine printed with a designated font and font size. The screenshots, thanks to todays "retina" displays are high resolution, but still a low DPI. Should I rescale/resize the images?
3. How can I handle emojis? The messaging app user has an option to insert an emoji. Again, the set of emojis is well defined. Can an OCR program be taught to learn these characters?

Image for reference 
[image: example image]

Comment: did you find any solutions ?

Comment: @cankemik i did... but obviously its a bit of code. briefly: using openCV to process the images. i take each speech bubble convert to grayscale. feed to tesseract to get the text. do all that in order... then i used some openCV method to match the emojis. i did use python.

Answer (score 0):

I build an algorithm to classify chat screenshot to json with "sender" and "partner" key index.

```
import tesserocr
from nostril import nonsense
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import pytesseract
import random
import string
import re
import numpy as np
from gibberish_detector import detector
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request
import nltk
from flask import Flask


def imageToText(url):
  # gibberish_detector set model
  Detector = detector.create_from_model('big.model')
  response = requests.get(url)

  # load image from url in PIL image and convert to RGB/jpg format
  img = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
  rgb_im = img.convert('RGB')

  # Decrease saturation of image
  converter = ImageEnhance.Color(rgb_im)
  pil_img = converter.enhance(0)

  # react image from url in open cv
  req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
  final = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

  #initialize tesserocr api
  api = tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI(path='tessdata')
  api.SetImage(pil_img)

  # differentiate all the chat boxes based of text line in array
  boxes = api.GetComponentImages(tesserocr.RIL.TEXTLINE, True)
  height, width, c = final.shape

  inc = int(0.01*width)
  list_all = []

  # cv2_imshow(final)

  for i, (im,box,_,_) in enumerate(boxes):
    x,y,w,h = box['x'],box['y'],box['w'],box['h']
    crop_img = final[max(0, y-inc):min(y+h+inc,height), max(0, x-inc):min(x+w+inc, width)]
    api.SetRectangle(box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h'])

    extractedInformation = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop_img)
    stringAll = extractedInformation.replace('|', 'I').replace('\n\x0c', ' ');

    try:
      if not Detector.is_gibberish(stringAll):
        if (x < 200 and stringAll != '0 ' and stringAll != '\x0c' and not re.search("(Type a message Send|Snapchat|Ne Sent|Delivered|Message\n\n)", stringAll) and not re.search("((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]))", stringAll)):
          list_all.append({"body": stringAll, "sender": 'Partner'})
        elif (x > 199 and stringAll != '0 ' and stringAll != '\x0c' and not re.search("Type a message Send|Snapchat|Ne Sent|Delivered|Message\n\n", stringAll) and not re.search("((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]))", stringAll)):
          list_all.append({"body": stringAll, "sender": 'Me'})
    except: ''

  return list_all

print(imageToText('https://b2358461.smushcdn.com/2358461/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/IMG_9559-710x1536.jpeg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1'))
```